# Fill Null Values with another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have a small Data frame,

```
    address                                  lat          lng
   `London UK                              24.90770     91.85030`
```

Like this

And another Large DataFrame Where there is only address like this.

```
address        Lat     Lng
London,UK      Nan     Nan
```

So I want to fill my large dataframe's Data with values from the small Dataset. I have no Idea How to do this.

Comment: try `map` and `fillna` `df2['lat'].fillna(df2['address'].map(df1.set_index('address')['lat'])`

Comment: Work's perfectly, Can you Please post this as a Answer?

Comment: better to close as duplicate, lots of answers for this already